# PHP include page index.php?page=GET safety preg_replace

Tags: php, beginner, security, file-system, dynamic-loading

I found a lot of working codes to include page in page on Internet but I could not find a safe code. So I decided to create one myself. The pages will be only stored in folder /pages/ and whitelist seems to be a good option.

Is the follow code safe?

```
<?php
$unsafe = $_GET['pagename'];
$page = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $unsafe);
if (empty($page)){
include('pages/default.php');
}
$pages = array('default', 'pageone', 'pagetwo', 'another', 'last');
if (isset($pages[$page])) {
    include('pages/' . $page . '.php');
} else {
include('pages/error-404.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: use `file_exists()` to check the file existence.

Comment: using file_Exists isn't really a safe option. You would need a lot of extra sanitation before passing something into file_exists. Just think of ../../et/password

Comment: Why aren't all nondigital characters stripped by `preg_replace()`. It seems obvious to me that `$pages` is an indexed array.  Is this code working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if a certain key exists in an array: `isset($pages[$page])` but you define the `$pages` array **without** keys, so they default to numeric ones. A much better approach is to skip the preg_replace thing (it is useless anyway) and create a router array:

`$router = array(
    'url' => 'pages/foobar.php',
    'default' => 'pages/default.php'
);`

This array maps urls to your internal pages. Then you check or the requested page exists:

```
if (isset($router[$_GET['page']]) {
    include $router[$_GET['page'];
} else {
    include $router['default'];
}
```